# Detect a root cert using web based code?

Tags: ssl, server, certificate, root, ca

I have been asked to write code that will be run a web server and will be called when the button on the website is clicked. They want me to detect if one or more specific root certificates are installed on the users' computer. If not, we will provide instructions on how to install the root certificates they need.

Does anyone know if it is even possible to detect root certificates in this way?